# Ipad KeyPad not displaying for the textbox that is placed inside jquery draggable div

Tags: asp.net, ipad, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a application that has jquery draggable div in it. 
I have placed four text fields inside the draggable div to get input from user.

Aspx:

```
    <div id="divAdd" runat="server">
    <input id="txtCode" placeholder="Location Code" maxlength="20" 
    type="text" runat="server" />
    <input id="txtName" placeholder="Location Code" maxlength="20" 
    type="text" runat="server" />
    ...
    </div>
    <div>
```

Javascript:

```
 $("#divAdd").draggable({ cursor: 'move', containment: '#divmap',
                drag: function () {
                    fnHandleMove();
                }
            });
```

I cant place the cursor in those textfield in IPAD by tapping on it. However Desktop version works fine.

> **If i comment out that javascript part, i am able to place the cursor and keypad shows.**

Is this bug with jquery UI-draggable or i am doing anything wrong?

Apart from JqueryUI.js i use JqueryTouchPunch.js and JSPlumb.js in the application.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK here's a solution if your `textfield` whatever HTML element is, isn't focusing,scrolling, selecting words, moving text cursor around the text and whatever different scenarios might come then you may override the **jquery.ui.touch.punch.js** script. I assume that your element isn't the draggable one but probably a child of it as my case was.

Put a class on your html element, for example `class="useDefault"`.
Then go to the script file and find that part:

```
...
function simulateMouseEvent (event, simulatedType) {

    // Ignore multi-touch events
    if (event.originalEvent.touches.length > 1) {
      return;
    }

    event.preventDefault();

    var touch = event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0],
        simulatedEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
....
```

As you can probably see `event.preventDefault();` assures that **jquery.ui.touch.punch.js**
overrides the default behaviors of the browser. To prevent that for our particular class node, make the following modifications:

```
if (event.originalEvent.touches.length > 1) {
  return;
}
var touch = event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0],
  simulatedEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
//As you can see here is your class element check
if (touch.target.className === "useDefault") {
  event.stopPropagation();
} else {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

This solution is tested with **webkit** browsers only and **jQuery UI Touch Punch 0.2.2** release.

Hope that quick solution helps, BR

Comment: You might want to make that `if ( $(touch.target).hasClass("useDefault") )` so it will work if it has other classes.

Answer (score 2):

A variation from kidwon idea:

In the same method, same part:

```
function simulateMouseEvent (event, simulatedType) {
    // Ignore multi-touch events
    if (event.originalEvent.touches.length > 1) {
        return;
    }

    event.preventDefault();
```

replace with:

```
function simulateMouseEvent (event, simulatedType) {
    // Ignore multi-touch events
    if (event.originalEvent.touches.length > 1) return;

    if (simulatedType == 'mouseup') {
        var elem = $(event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].target);
        if (elem.is("input") || elem.is("textarea")) elem.focus();
        else event.preventDefault();
    } else event.preventDefault();
```

Hope it helps.