# Overflow scroll not working on jquery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, cordova, touch

I am writing iOS apps using the Phonegap framework.I done dragging function home page on my app.Using jquery ui and touch punch js.The reference link is https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch#readme.
Now i had one problem. The overflow scrolling is not working on iPhone and ipad.
If i remove dragging function,it's work fine.What i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Same Issue is addressed in the following stack overflow question. Please refer the link below.

[Ipad KeyPad not displaying for the textbox that is placed inside jquery draggable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929680/ipad-keypad-not-displaying-for-the-textbox-that-is-placed-inside-jquery-draggabl)